# How to use XML file in AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm attempting to create a navigation and content system via a single XML file and using AS3.
I have succeeded in importing XML and styling it.

**I am stuck on  how to create the navigation system.**

Sample XML:

```
?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<XML>

<pages>

<page>
<recordnumber>1</recordnumber/>
<locatn>1.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</locatn>
<first>Consectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole</first>
<firstpara>Stie curae tristique et, hac aliquam mattis eu platea pulvinar. Arcu erat id eleifend lacuconsectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole.</firstpara>
<bodytext>hac aliquam mattis eu platea pulvinar. Arcu erat id eleifend lacuconsectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole.
s mollis hac et leo vitae imperdiet habitasse nunc cum semper, elementum ornare eu condimentum vehicula litora consequat feugiat facilisis etiam ridiculus metus vel. 
Hendrerit parturient nisl dis enim odio rutrum dignissim, imperdiet dictumst facilisis ac tincidunt luctus at suscipit, tortor montes libero fringilla dui proin.
Egestas tempor blandit condimentum conubia nibh sapien penatibus tincidunt dapibus morbi, sed urna lacinia arcu at senectus duis nostra sollicitudin purus, malesuad
a platea dis mi aenean sodales class sociis rhoncus. Sociis integer commodo dictumst nibh ridiculus nullam dis quam, sapien sem quisque molestie vestibulum semper imperdiet 
egestas, tempor porttitor neque eu nam vel morbi. Metus volutpat tortor ad fermentum parturient montes malesuada per lacinia ac a taciti massa, 
arcu ligula fusce purus pulvinar erat porttitor egestas proin sollicitudin magnis.</bodytext>
</page>

<page>  
<recordnumber>2</recordnumber/>
<locatn>1.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</locatn>
<first>Consectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole</first>
<firstpara>Stie curae tristique et, hac aliquam mattis eu platea pulvinar. Arcu erat id eleifend lacuconsectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole.</firstpara>
<bodytext>hac aliquam mattis eu platea pulvinar. Arcu erat id eleifend lacuconsectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole.
s mollis hac et leo vitae imperdiet habitasse nunc cum semper, elementum ornare eu condimentum vehicula litora consequat feugiat facilisis etiam ridiculus metus vel. 
Hendrerit parturient nisl dis enim odio rutrum dignissim, imperdiet dictumst facilisis ac tincidunt luctus at suscipit, tortor montes libero fringilla dui proin.
Egestas tempor blandit condimentum conubia nibh sapien penatibus tincidunt dapibus morbi, sed urna lacinia arcu at senectus duis nostra sollicitudin purus, malesuad
a platea dis mi aenean sodales class sociis rhoncus. Sociis integer commodo dictumst nibh ridiculus nullam dis quam, sapien sem quisque molestie vestibulum semper imperdiet 
egestas, tempor porttitor neque eu nam vel morbi. Metus volutpat tortor ad fermentum parturient montes malesuada per lacinia ac a taciti massa, 
arcu ligula fusce purus pulvinar erat porttitor egestas proin sollicitudin magnis.</bodytext>
</page>

<page>
<recordnumber>3</recordnumber/>
<locatn>1.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</locatn>
<first>Consectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole</first>
<firstpara>Stie curae tristique et, hac aliquam mattis eu platea pulvinar. Arcu erat id eleifend lacuconsectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole.</firstpara>
<bodytext>hac aliquam mattis eu platea pulvinar. Arcu erat id eleifend lacuconsectetur adipiscing elit, tortor faucibus ac vestibulum mole.
s mollis hac et leo vitae imperdiet habitasse nunc cum semper, elementum ornare eu condimentum vehicula litora consequat feugiat facilisis etiam ridiculus metus vel. 
Hendrerit parturient nisl dis enim odio rutrum dignissim, imperdiet dictumst facilisis ac tincidunt luctus at suscipit, tortor montes libero fringilla dui proin.
Egestas tempor blandit condimentum conubia nibh sapien penatibus tincidunt dapibus morbi, sed urna lacinia arcu at senectus duis nostra sollicitudin purus, malesuad
a platea dis mi aenean sodales class sociis rhoncus. Sociis integer commodo dictumst nibh ridiculus nullam dis quam, sapien sem quisque molestie vestibulum semper imperdiet 
egestas, tempor porttitor neque eu nam vel morbi. Metus volutpat tortor ad fermentum parturient montes malesuada per lacinia ac a taciti massa, 
arcu ligula fusce purus pulvinar erat porttitor egestas proin sollicitudin magnis.</bodytext>
</page>

</pages>

</XML>
```

Image of the **layout** guide:
[image]
I assume the above is addressing fellow child nodes and parent nodes to create the menu and links

My code so far:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.display.SimpleButton



//I Set they' location on stage where the first box will live 
var yPlacement: int = 60;
//Set the "x" location on stage where all boxes will line up vertically 
var xPlacement: int = 0;
// Set the distance each box should be apart here 
var distance: int = 480;


// Initialize the XML, place the xml file name, initialize the URLRequest 
// put URLRequest into a new URLLoader, and add event listener on 
// myLoader listening for when the XML loading is complete 

var myXML: XML = new XML();
var XML_URL: String = "pages3.xml";
var myXMLURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var xmlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
xmlLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);




//Create the xmlLoaded function
function xmlLoaded(event: Event): void {

    // Place the xml data into the myXML object 
    myXML = XML(xmlLoader.data);
    // Initialize and give var name to the new extemal XMLDocument 
    var xmlDoc: XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    // Ignore spacing around nodes 
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    //Define a new name for the loaded XML that is the data in myLoader
    var menuXML: XML = XML(xmlLoader.data);
    //Parse the XML data into a readable format 
    xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());

    // Run the "for each"
    //  loop to iterate through all of the menu items listed in the external XML file
    // This all pertains to the complete box that needs to be scrolled
    /* var scrollCompleteholder: Shape = new Shape; */

    ////scrollCompleteholder.graphics.beginFill(0xF0F0F0);
    //scrollCompleteholder.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x333333);
    //scrollCompleteholder.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 3840, 860);




    for each(var page: XML in myXML..page) {



        // Access the value of the "recordnumber" node in our external XML file
        var list_recordnumber: String = page.recordnumber.toString();

        // Access the value of the "locatn" node in our external XML file
        var list_locatn: String = page.locatn.toString();

        // Access the value of the "first" node in our external XML file
        var list_first: String = page.first.toString();

        // Access the value of the "first" node in our external XML file
        var list_firstpara: String = page.firstpara.toString();

        // Access the value of the "first" node in our external XML file
        var list_bodytext: String = page.bodytext.toString();


        // How many mc's attach to the scrollpane
        var num_clips: int = 155;
        // y value for next object to be placed
        var nextXPos: int = 0;
        // counter for()
        var n: int = 0;
        //Create a movieclip (mc) to hold the attached items





        // This all pertains to the style of the Box that holds each person
        var rect: Shape = new Shape;
        //var color: Number = 0x333333;
        rect.graphics.beginFill(0xF0F0F0);
        rect.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x666666);
        rect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 424, 730);

        // This all pertains to the text fields that give our boxes their labels, alter values to your liking


        var myText1: TextField = new TextField();
        myText1.text = list_recordnumber;
        myText1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        myText1.x = 4;
        myText1.y = 4;
        myText1.width = 384;
        // get the Textformat of the first character
        var TF: TextFormat = myText_01.getTextFormat(0, 1)
        // set the font color
        TF.color = 0xCCCCCC;
        // put it on the whole text
        myText1.setTextFormat(TF);
        addChild(myText1);

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        var myText2: TextField = new TextField();
        myText2.text = list_locatn;
        myText2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        myText2.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        myText2.width = 384;
        myText2.wordWrap = true;
        myText2.embedFonts = true;
        //myText2.scroll = true;
        myText2.multiline = true;
        myText2.x = 4;
        myText2.y = 144;
        // get the Textformat of the first character
        var TF2: TextFormat = myText_02.getTextFormat(0, 1);
        // set the font color
        TF2.color = 0x000000;

        // put it on the whole text
        myText2.setTextFormat(TF2);
        addChild(myText2);

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        var myText3: TextField = new TextField();
        myText3.text = list_first;
        myText3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        myText3.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        myText3.width = 384;
        myText3.wordWrap = true;
        myText3.embedFonts = true;
        //myText3.scroll = true;
        myText3.multiline = true;
        myText3.x = 4;
        myText3.y = 26;
        // get the Textformat of the first character
        var TF3: TextFormat = myText_03.getTextFormat(0, 1);
        // set the font color
        TF3.color = 0x339900;

        // put it on the whole text
        myText3.setTextFormat(TF3);
        addChild(myText3);

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        var myText4: TextField = new TextField();
        myText4.text = list_firstpara;
        myText4.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        myText4.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        myText4.width = 384;
        myText4.wordWrap = true;
        myText4.embedFonts = true;
        //myText4.scroll = true;
        myText4.multiline = true;
        myText4.x = 4;
        myText4.y = 184;
        // get the Textformat of the first character
        var TF4: TextFormat = myText_04.getTextFormat(0, 1);
        // set the font color
        TF4.color = 0x999999;

        // put it on the whole text
        myText4.setTextFormat(TF4);
        addChild(myText4);


        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        var myText5: TextField = new TextField();
        //var maxScrollV = 440;

        myText5.text = list_bodytext;
        /*      myText5.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;*/
        myText5.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        myText5.width = 370;
        myText5.height = 440;
        myText5.wordWrap = true;
        myText5.embedFonts = true;
        //myText5.scrollV = true;

        //myText5.scrollV = myText5.maxScrollV;

        myText5.scrollV++;
        myText5.multiline = true;
        myText5.x = 4;
        myText5.y = 280;

        // get the Textformat of the first character
        var TF5: TextFormat = myText_05.getTextFormat(0, 1);
        // set the font color
        TF5.color = 0x000000;

        // put it on the whole text
        myText5.setTextFormat(TF5);

        addChild(myText5);

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        var Timeline_mc = new MovieClip();

        //MovieClip holder for each box graphic and text labels to organize everything into container 
        var clip_mc = new MovieClip();

        // Add the rectangle graphic 
        //clip_mc.addChild(rect);

        // Add the text fields 
        for (n = 0; n < num_clips; n++) {

            clip_mc.addChild(myText1);
            clip_mc.addChild(myText2);
            clip_mc.addChild(myText3);
            clip_mc.addChild(myText4);
            clip_mc.addChild(myText5);

            trace(myXML.recordnumber.@number);
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        }

        // Put the new movieClip on stage now
        addChild(clip_mc);

        // Now apply it in its offset Y position to the stage
        clip_mc.y = yPlacement;
        // X position that it will be placed on stage 
        clip_mc.x = xPlacement;
        // Offset each one in the loop to make sure they don't just get put right on top of each other 
        xPlacement = xPlacement + distance;


        addChild(Timeline_mc);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use UI Component approach rather than single piece of script. Create **Page** component that accepts **XML** node and views its content appropriately. Then, one level up, you need a **PageView** that accepts an **XMLList** and creates the collection of **Page**s with the line of the buttons to scroll and focus a **Page** by a given index. One more hierarchy level up: the **MainView** layout, that shows the title and holds the **PageView**. On each level the amount of coding is small and comprehensible, and you can test each thing separately to finally build the whole wall with these bricks.

Comment: Dear Organis, Thank You for the pointers. This is my first attempt at using XML so will study at the Adobe site and get back to you.

Comment: I think it's not a question of **XML**. **XML** is a simple data structure you can trivially extract data from. It's more about decomposing your big task into smaller ones and the overall hierarchy of the project.

Comment: Hello again Organis, I am stuck in parsing the xml toString. 

trace(externalXML.toXMLString()); 
trace(externalXML.toString()); 

both show the raw XML file with the tagging and nodes... I don't seem to make this produce a text string.

I am using Animate CC. The latest version. Admittedly my previous effort was cumbersome and at least it produced a result (2-3 days ago). That parsed the XML and used text format to render the typography...

I added a text area component and can get the XML into this area but then again not to render as text. Any pointers please?

Comment: by the way. this intended as as3 not for AIR

Comment: Ah, I think I get what's the problem here. Ofc, an XML node is a node with tags and everything. If you have a node like **<first>Title Caption</first>**, the text is the child node, so the correct way to extract **only text** would be **... = page.first.children().toString();**

Comment: Thank You. So is my thinking on the first part of laying out the pages correct so far? As I will move onto working on the navigation next...